# Pandas - Getting Business Hours between Date and Current Time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I know this is a somewhat frequently asked question but I've only found one solution that allows me to use local calendars and holidays by using the `businesstimedelta` library.

My current code for getting data between two date columns **works**.

df is as follows (created date column made with `pd.datetime.now()`:

```
Index   Created Date        Updated Date        Diff Hrs    Current Date
10086   2016-11-04 16:00:00 2016-11-11 11:38:00 35.633333   2018-05-29 10:09:11.291391
10087   2016-11-04 16:03:00 2016-11-29 12:54:00 132.850000  2018-05-29 10:09:11.291391
10088   2016-11-04 16:05:00 2016-11-16 08:05:00 56.916667   2018-05-29 10:09:11.291391
10089   2016-11-04 16:17:00 2016-11-08 11:37:00 11.333333   2018-05-29 10:09:11.291391
10090   2016-11-04 16:20:00 2016-11-16 09:58:00 57.633333   2018-05-29 10:09:11.291391
10091   2016-11-04 16:32:00 2016-11-08 11:10:00 10.633333   2018-05-29 10:09:11.291391
```

Working code to produce difference between `Created Date` and `Updated Date` is below:

```
import datetime
import pytz
import businesstimedelta
import holidays as pyholidays

workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(9),
    end_time=datetime.time(17),
    working_days=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])


vic_holidays = pyholidays.AU(prov='VIC')
holidays = businesstimedelta.HolidayRule(vic_holidays)
businesshrs = businesstimedelta.Rules([workday, holidays])

def BusHrs(start, end):
    return businesshrs.difference(start,end).hours+float(businesshrs.difference(start,end).seconds)/float(3600)

df['Diff Hrs'] = df.apply(lambda row: BusHrs(row['Created Date'], row['Updated Date']), axis=1)
```

It takes a while to run but works - however trying to create a new column from the difference between current time and updated time ex. `df['Time Since Last Update'] = df.apply(lambda row: BusHrs(row['Current Date'], row['Updated Date']), axis=1)` fails/takes forever and I have no idea why.

Any help on calculating `Time Since Last Update` is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inverse `row['Current Date']` and `row['Updated Date']` in your `df['Time Since Last Update']`, then with

```
df['Time Since Last Update'] = df.apply(lambda row: BusHrs(row['Updated Date'], row['Current Date']), axis=1)
```

it should work. I assume `start` can't be after `end` in the function `businesshrs.difference`.
Also, if you want to speed up a bit your code, do:

```
def BusHrs(start, end):
    diff_businesshrs = businesshrs.difference(start,end)
    # like this you calculate only once businesshrs.difference(start,end)
    return diff_businesshrs.hours+float(diff_businesshrs.seconds)/float(3600)
```

EDIT I think I found a faster way. because the business hours between things from 2016 to now is long to calculate for each row, I think you can do faster by calculating hours between two successives Update Date and then `sum` over these partial calculation until the Current Date. You need two temporary columns, one with shifted Updated Date and the other one with partial business hours

```
df = df.sort_values('Updated Date').reset_index()
df['Shift Date'] = df['Updated Date'].shift(-1).fillna(pd.datetime.now())
df['BsnHrs Partial'] = df.apply(lambda row: BusHrs(row['Updated Date'], row['Shift Date']), axis=1)
df['Time Since Last Update'] = df.apply(lambda row: df['BsnHrs Partial'][row.name:].sum(), axis=1)
df = df.drop(['Shift Date','BsnHrs Partial'],1).set_index('index') # drop and reindex
df = df.sort_index() #if you want to go back to the original order
```

Comment: Great, thanks. It's definitely faster and working, though with ~40k rows still will likely take a few hours. Is there any faster way than df.apply? Cheers.

Comment: Cheers Ben, you are right. It definitely goes quicker the smaller the delta between the two dates. The `Updated Date` spans back from 2015 until today so no luck just taking the max.. but you did give me the thought of at least converting 2015-2017 to 2018, running the difference then adding back on 1/2 years. It's not ideal and haven't had time to test yet but I will let you know.

Actually I can't convert all 2017 to 2018 because I will get some with Dec 2018 start - current date. Damn!

Comment: Apologies did not see your edit - investigating now.

Comment: What a novel solution, works a treat! <1-2 min run time on 40k rows. For curiosities sake - what exactly does  `[row.name:]` do in the lambda function? I get that it sums up to the current row but I've never seen that notation. Great stuff.